# Flutter : it is possible to implement custom type union?

Tags: flutter, dart

in dart there is such feature like `abstract class FutureOr<T> {}`. The `FutureOr<int>` type is actually the "type union" of the types int and Future.

can we imitate this ?

```
abstract class AnimalOr<T> {}

abstract class Animal{}

abstract class Human{}
```

is it possible to do something like this? :

```
AnimalOr<T> pickCreature<T> (){
  final result = calculate();
  if(conditionIsMet){
    return result as T;
  }
  return result as Animal;
 }

AnimalOr<Human> creature = pickCreature<Human>();
```

Comment: You could use Either<Animal, Human>. https://pub.dev/packages/dartz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `FutureOr<X>` type is actually useful to say "I will get X, but I don't know if it will be synchronous or asynchronous. Your type does not have any such implication. A `FutureOr<X>` at some point (except exceptions obviously) will always be reduced to an `X`, your type will always stay "either one or the other". You cannot get one from the other.

It seems like you are looking for an `Either<TLeft, TRight>` type. You can write one youself, or you can look at packages that already did this.

For example

- https://pub.dev/packages/either_type
- https://pub.dev/packages/dartz
- https://pub.dev/packages/multiple_result